# Ajuda no código impressão de caracters repetidos

Tags: java, if, caracteres, java-processing

Eu quero imprimir somente os caracteres que estão repetidos na *string* e a quantidade de repetições. Se ele aparece somente uma vez, eu não quero imprimir ele. Preciso ajuda com a expressão boolena.

- Como faço para verificar se o caracter é repetido? e
- já foi encontrado?

Código:

```
char Char;
int count;
String s = "Par programming is fun!";
s = s.toLowerCase();
for (Char = 0; Char <= s.length()-1; Char++) {
    count = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++) {
        if (s.charAt(i) == s.charAt(Char) && !(s.charAt(Char)==Char)) {
            count++;
        }
    }
    System.out.println("Number of occurences of " + s.charAt(Char) + " is " + count);
}
```

Comment: Não, uso processing que é um subset do java.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A sua solução ficou perto de funcionar. Apenas lhe falta considerar ocorrências com mais do que `1` e desconsiderar letras que já foram processadas. Existem muitas possibilidades para resolver as letras já processadas, e uma delas seria guardar numa `String` aparte quais a que já sairam e não considerar essas.

Mantendo a sua lógica original e fazendo estes ajustes ficaria assim:

```
char Char;
int count;
String s = "Par programming is fun!";
s = s.toLowerCase();
String carateresSaidos = ""; //para manter registo das letras que ja sairam

for (Char = 0; Char <= s.length()-1; Char++) {
    count = 0;

    if (carateresSaidos.indexOf(s.charAt(Char)) == -1){ //se ainda não saiu
        for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++) {
            if (s.charAt(i) == s.charAt(Char)) {
                count++;
            }
        }
        if (count > 1){ //mostra apenas se é repetida, ou seja, se há mais que uma
            System.out.println("Number of occurences of "+s.charAt(Char) + " is " + count);
        }
        carateresSaidos += s.charAt(Char); //adicionar esta letra as que já sairam
    }
}
```

[Exemplo no Ideone](https://ideone.com/iSOdFh)

No entanto existem soluções bem mais performáticas, que não implicam utilizar dois `for`(que é uma solução quadrática). Mostro uma solução, equiparada à última solução do @Felipe, mas utilizando um array nativo para contagem das várias letras. Esta solução assume que a `String` contem apenas caráteres ASCII.

```
int[] contagens = new int[256];
for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); ++i)
    contagens[s.charAt(i)]++;

for (int i = 0; i < 256; ++i){
    if(contagens[i] > 1){
        System.out.println("Number of occurences of " + (char)i + " is " + contagens[i]);
    }
}
```

[Veja esta solução também no Ideone](https://ideone.com/gD2w9S)

O primeiro `for` passa em cada letra e aumenta `1` na posição corresponde no array. A posição vai corresponder ao número da letra na tabela ASCII. O segundo `for` apenas mostra as contagens que ficaram com mais que `1`.

Comment: Estou sem tempo, mas era isso que eu estava querendo fazer.

Comment: O primeiro exemplo de código está bem próximo do que eu estava querendo fazer. Valeu pela ajuda!

Answer (score 1):

É mais simples, nesse caso, transformar a `String` em um `array` de caracteres. E, também, remover os caracteres da `String` que já foram verificados para que eles não sejam contabilizados múltiplas vezes.

```
String text = "Par programming is fun!";
text = text.toLowerCase();
for(char c1 : text.toCharArray()) {
    int count = 0;
    for(char c2 : text.toCharArray()) {
        if(c1 == c2) {
            count++;
        }
    }
    text = text.replaceAll(String.valueOf(c1) , "");
    if(count > 1) {
        System.out.println("Number of occurences of " + c1 + " is " + count);
    }
}
```

Uma outra opção que não faz uso de laços encadeados:

```
texto = texto.toLowerCase();
for(char c = texto.charAt(0); !texto.isEmpty(); c = texto.charAt(0)) {
    String temp = texto.replaceAll(String.valueOf(c), "");
    int numeroDeOcorrencias = texto.length() - temp.length();
    texto = temp;
    if(numeroDeOcorrencias > 1) {
        System.out.println("Number of occurences of " + c + " is " + numeroDeOcorrencias);
    }
    if(texto.isEmpty()) {
        break;
    }
}
```

Uma solução mais simples utilizando Java 8.

```
String text = "Par programming is fun!";
text.chars()
    .mapToObj(c -> Character.toLowerCase((char) c))         //Cria uma Stream como todos os chars da String
    .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Function.identity(), 
                                    Collectors.counting())) //Conta quantas vezes cada char aparece na String
    .forEach((key, value) -> {
        //Se o char aparece mais de uma veze, ele é exibido
        if(value > 1) {
            System.out.println("Number of occurences of " + key + " is " + value);
        }
    });
```

Comment: Tenho a impressão que isto não funcionará, leia o comentário acima.

Comment: @Maniero Não tinha percebido. Adicionei uma forma mais simples de fazer a verificação.